# Is it possible to hide attribute declarations in Doxygen?

Tags: c#, doxygen

In C#, I have some static readonly attributes that look like the following:

```
/// Provides the thingie.
public static readonly SomeClass Thingie = new SomeClass("Thingie Name");
```

within a larger class. Doxygen generates a Static Public Attributes section in the documentation (as expected) which contains an entry for `Thingie`, which I do want. However, it also includes the declaration, like so:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|static readonly SomeClass | Thingie = new SomeClass("Thingie Name");|
|                          | Provides the thingie.                   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I would simply like to hide the `= new SomeClass("Thingie Name");` bit. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES` to `0` in the configuration file to hide initializers globally.

You can also use `/** @cond */ thing to hide from doxygen /** @endcond */` to hide something locally.